# assemble a variable based off input swift

Tags: arrays, swift, variables, input

Is it possible to call a different variable based off of say a switch and a text input?

say the text input is 40 and the switch is true, can I call the variable var401, where as if the text input was 25 and the switch was false I would want to call the variable 250. I have a large amount of arrays that are all defined by different names that I would like to call based on the input from the user.

Thanks!

Comment: `Is it possible` No. But the functionnality you want is easily achieved by using a *dictionary*. Have a look: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that you have a dictionary of arrays where each key of the dictionary is of the type varNNB where NN is text input and B is true or false here's what you can do.

```
let arrayOfDict = ["var401":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], "var250":[2,4,6,8,10]]
let status = true
let input = "40"
var suffix = status ? "1" : "0"
let key = "var"+input+suffix
print(arrayOfDict[key])
```

Basically you create a key string by combining the input and the bool variable and then prefixing it with var. The combined string is then used to key into the dictionary. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that should work, sorry I don't have a high enough reputation to give you a vote.

Comment: That's fine. Once you get enough upvote and accept the answer.